# Batch processing of historical streaming data with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have an application in mind and I am having a hard time figuring out the most efficient way to write it. We have a live feed of data that we wish to process with Spark Streaming.

We are keeping a running state for a group of items.

For example,

```
group_id,item_id,timestamp,state
1,1,'2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000',1    -> group 1 has 1 items in state 1
2,1,'2016-01-01 00:00:01+0000',0    -> group 2 has 0 items in state 1
1,2,'2016-01-01 00:00:10+0000',1    -> group 1 has 2 items in state 1
2,3,'2016-01-01 00:01:01+0000',1    -> group 2 has 1 items in state 1
1,4,'2016-01-01 00:05:00+0000',0    -> group 1 has 2 items in state 1
2,2,'2016-01-01 00:07:00+0000',1    -> group 2 has 2 items in state 1
```

The spark streaming application is very well suited for `updateStateByKey`

However, we also log all of this data to Cassandra. Because some data might come in late, it is important for us to run a periodic (daily, weekly, etc) fixup job that looks at all of the logged Cassandra data and compute the same running state.

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE state_tracking (
    group_id,
    year int,
    time timestamp,
    item_id int,
    state int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((group_id, year), time, item_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

This is the part I am having trouble with.

If possible, I would like to reuse as much of the Streaming code as possible. I would also like the job to have reasonable performance.

The entire dataset is very large, however, there are many thousands of groups. One group will definitely fit in the memory of a single executor.

I am using `pypark-cassandra`.

It seems like using `groupByKey` will give me a list of all events associated with a `group_id`, which could then be sorted  and iterated over.

`mapPartitions` also looks like it could be useful, but I need to make sure that all records for a `group_id` are in a single partition. I also need to worry about sort order.

My current best guess is to use `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` to partition by `group_id` and then use `mapPartitions` to iterate through the sorted data.

Am I on the right track, or am I way off? Has anyone dealt with large, order sensitive data in a batch Spark job?

Comment: How is your schema looking like? You will need to line up your Cassandra table schema for an optimal batch fetch. Otherwise you will be doing full table scans that take forever.

Comment: I have added my Cassandra schema. I am using a partition key of `(group_id, year)` and clustering by `time`.